# How to use ternary operator in php at queal value

Tags: php, ternary-operator

This table print at index page using jQuery.Ajax().it returns only true part at every time even condition is also false

```
$data['1']['0']['available']= 0 to 10; 
echo "<div class='services'>
                        <div class='media-body'>
                            <h3 class='media-heading'>Check avability</h3>
                            <div class='table-responsive'>
                                <table class='table'>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr><th>Sr.no</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>
                                        <tr><td>1</td>
                                        <td>Delux</td>";
                                            echo ($data['1']['0']['available'] < 10) ? '<td>Available</td>': '<td>Not Available</td>' ;
                                        echo"<td>".$data['1']['0']['available']."</td>
                                        <td><button class='btn btn-success'>Book Now</button></td>"; echo "</tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>";
```

Comment: Sorry, it is completely unclear what you ask... Your use of the ternary operator looks fine syntactically. So what is the issue?

Comment: it returns only first value every time.

Comment: did u check properly?? coz its working fine...

Comment: It certainly will resolve to `true` for vallues [6..9] and to `false` for value 10.

Comment: Just a really wild guess here: maybe you have a caching issue when testing by reloading in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using the keys as strings because they are defined as strings or you are doing it by mistake. If they are really strings then you should change them in my example as well.

```
echo intval($data[1][0]['available']) < 10
    ? "<td> Available </td>"
    : "<td>Not Available</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct code and your logic is true and as per your code it should return 'Not Available'. I think this is the only way to write ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think the array is returning string value please confirm that array returns string or integer. If it returns string then first convert it into integer then try. I think after that it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your value return in string format.
you try this code :

```
    <?php
$data['1']['0']['available']=$any_numeric_value ; 
echo "<div class='services'>
        <div class='media-body'>
           <h3 class='media-heading'>Check avability</h3>
               <div class='table-responsive'>
                   <table class='table'>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr><th>Sr.no</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>
                           <tr><td>1</td>
                              <td>Delux</td>".(int($data['1']['0']['available'] < 10) ? '<td>Available</td>': '<td>Not Available</td>' ).
    "<td>".$data['1']['0']['available']."</td>
                                        <td><button class='btn btn-success'>Book Now</button></td></tr>
                       </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I have tried this code is working.